# How do I use my input from two cases in a third case, all while keeping it in one switch?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have the following code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int menuSel;

do {
    System.out.println("1. Adult Tickets");
    System.out.println("2. Child Tickets");
    System.out.println("3. Finalise Order");
    System.out.println("4. Cancel Order");
    System.out.println("Please select an option from the list:");
    menuSel = in.nextInt();

    switch(menuSel) {
        case 1: 
            System.out.println("Number of tickets:");
            int adult = in.nextInt(); 
            double adultTotal = (adult * 15.5);
            System.out.println("Total price for " + adult + " tickets is $" + adultTotal);
            break;

        case 2: 
            System.out.println("Number of tickets:");
            int child = in.nextInt();
            double childTotal = (child * 5.75);
            System.out.println("Total price for " + child + " tickets is $" + childTotal);
            break;

        case 3: 
            adult = ?;
            child = ?;          
            adultTotal = (adult * 15.5);
            childTotal = (child * 5.75);
            System.out.println("Your order of " + adult + "adult ticket(s) and " + child + "child ticket(s) amounts to $" +(childTotal + adultTotal));
    }
}
```

In this code I have an issue with case 3. I cannot seem to get the variables 'adult' and 'child' to display properly. I get the "local variable may not be initialized" error. I do not want to declare variables at the main because I am inputting the values in case 1 and 2. I would like case 3 to display what I input in case 1 in case 2 as values.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I have been stuck at this problem for 3 hours and unfortunately I do not know how to progress further.

Comment: You're using four variables in your third case, none of which are initialized within the scope. You should initialize/declare these variables before your `switch`, that way each `case` can reference and modify them.

Comment: Think of it from the compiler's point of view. *It doesn't know* that in practice those variables will have been initialised, it just sees that there is a pathway through your code where they haven't been. In this case it makes sense to increase the scope of those variables and initialise them to a sensible value (`0` in this scenario should be perfectly acceptable - if you didn't enter any child tickets then you don't want to be adding any to the order).

Comment: Update. I declared adult and child as 0 initially and it worked. Thanks for the help guys. I did that earlier too but it did not come out correctly, must've had an oversight. Cheers

Comment: Then that's the problem that you really need to be asking about

Comment: @LanceCha d you declare them to 0 outside of the do statement as well?  If you declared them to be 0 between the do statement and the switch statement, then every time you come back to the menu its going to reset the values of adult and child back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

The variables in your third case may not be initialized since you declare them in cases 1 and 2, but don't repeat the declaration for case 3.  For a  rudimentary explanation, the compiler sees a scenario where the program goes straight to case 3, and thus skips the initialization of the variables, and the compiler cannot use a variable that has not been properly initialized.  The fix here is to declare them in each case, or declare them prior to hitting the switch statement (example below).

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int menuSel, adult, child;
double adultTotal, childTotal;

do{
    System.out.println("1. Adult Tickets");
    System.out.println("2. Child Tickets");
    System.out.println("3. Finalise Order");
    System.out.println("4. Cancel Order");
    System.out.println("Please select an option from the list:");
    menuSel = in.nextInt();

    switch(menuSel){
        case 1: System.out.println("Number of tickets:");
            adult = in.nextInt(); 
            adultTotal=(adult*15.5);
            System.out.println("Total price for " + adult + " tickets is $" + adultTotal);
            break;
        case 2: System.out.println("Number of tickets:");
            child = in.nextInt();
            childTotal=(child*5.75);
            System.out.println("Total price for " + child + " tickets is $" + childTotal);
            break;
        case 3: adult=?;
            child=?;            
            adultTotal=(adult*15.5);
            childTotal=(child*5.75);
            System.out.println("Your order of " + adult + "adult ticket(s) and "+ child + "child ticket(s) amounts to $" +(childTotal+adultTotal));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then, you can not see case 3 executed with break statement in case 1 and case 2 provided the switch enter into them. Mostly, case 3 can be treated as default if you must always enter it and you remove break form case 1 and case 2.

```
switch(a) {

     case 1:

     case 2:

     case 3:

     default:
         // This will be entered if no break statement is encountered.
}
```